# Query shows the all value from table A and the unmached values from table B

Tags: sql, matching

I think it is very easy, but can't figure out.

I have a table A like this:

```
Id|A1  |A2
1 |5   |2
2 |5   |3
3 |6   |9
4 |7   |null
```

and table B like this:

```
Id|B1
1 |1
2 |2
3 |3
4 |9
```

I would like to write a select with this output:

```
R1 | R2 
5  | 1
5  | 9
6  | 1
6  | 2
6  | 3
7  | 1
7  | 2
7  | 3
7  | 9
```

I can get the unmatched values for a given A value:

```
SELECT * FROM B 
WHERE B.id NOT IN (
    SELECT A2 FROM A WHERE A2 = 5
)
```

but can't build the right SQL.

Is there anybody can help me in this subject?

Comment: Please explain using an explanation or pseudo-code the table you want to create. How should tables A and B be combined to create the output?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I wonder what is the exact relationship. TableA.A2 = TableB.Id? TableA.A2 = TableB.B1?. Please make clear the relationship and what the desired output columns are (R1 and R2 is not descriptive)

Comment: select B.* from B left join A on B.CommonField = A.CommonField where A.Id is null

Comment: The goal is to create a registration/reservation page for a parental conference. Table A contains the teacher's id (A1), and their occupied appointment time id (A2) . Table B contains all the possible appointment times (ie.: 16:00, 16:10, ...). The query should display all the teacher names, and their selectable (not occupied) appointment times. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then filter out the ones that already match:

```
select a.a1, b.b1
from (select distinct a1 from a) a cross join
     b left join
     a aa
     on aa.a1 = a.a1 and aa.b1 = b.b1
where aa.a1 is null;
```

Comment: After translation for the real situation the sql is:

Comment: select * from 
(select distinct teacher_id, appointm_id from reservations) rs1 
cross join appointments a 
left join reservations rs2 on rs2.teacher_id = rs1.teacher_id and rs2.appointm_id = rs1.appointm_id
where rs2.teacher_id is null

Comment: but it results in empty set :-(

Comment: @katonacs . . . You should ask *another* question with appropriate data and desired results.  You clearly did not do a good job describing the data in this question, or at least translating this answer to your data.

Comment: Gordon Linoff: when I left the select in he parenthesis everything works fine! Thank you for your help!!! :-)